# Sqlite3 GROUPBY with HAVING and ORDER BY not working

Tags: sqlite, group-by, having-clause, subquery

I have a SQL query that is calculating the correct output, and is even doing the order by correctly, however it is not executing the having clause. am i doing something wrong? It is not filtering the percentages at all.

```
select table1.name as theme, 
  printf("%.2f", cast(count(table2.name)as float)/(select count(table2.name) 
  from table1
  join table2
  where table1.id = table2.theme_id)*100) as percentage from table1
join table2
where table1.id = table2.theme_id
  group by table1.id
  having percentage >=5.00
  order by percentage desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since `printf()` returns a string, the calculated column `percentage` is a string and you compare it to `5.00` which is a number.
This comparison can't give you what you expect because it is not a comparison between numbers.
One way to solve this is to drop `printf()` and use `round()` which returns a number instead:

```
select table1.name as theme, 
  round(cast(count(table2.name)as float)/(select count(table2.name) 
  from table1
  join table2
  where table1.id = table2.theme_id)*100, 2) as percentage from table1
join table2
where table1.id = table2.theme_id
  group by table1.id
  having percentage >=5.00
  order by percentage desc;
```

or cast `percentage` to `float`:

```
having cast(percentage as float) >= 5.00
```